Elasticsearch Match Specified
So i have a Number that follows a specific pattern.
AR-{number} when searching for a specified one, f.e. AR-1033
i have the simple analyzer defined globally, as theres different fields, that require simple.
I've tried applying the keyword and whitespace analyzers to the number field and boost that field. But i get an empty response.
if set to standard it matches every document, cuz all of them have that AR-{number} field.
The Same thing applies to different fields in other indices following different patterns (ER{number}, C{number} etc)
(And yes, i am Escaping the "-" in my queries, so it gets send to Elasticsearch like "AR-1033")
Im Using Elasticseach 7.10 with the FOSElasticaBundle, but when i've been trying to search in Kibana, i get the same results as when Searching via the IndexManager, so that shouldn't really matter.
Any Help is majorly appreciated!

Can you please add sample data, index mapping as well as what is your current DSL query ?

You could introduce a multifield. The multifield contains a source text, its letters and number for separate search. Letters and numbers are extracted by regular expressions
Mapping
PUT /numbers_in_pattern
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "number_extracter_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": false,
                    "patterns": [
                        """[A-Z]+-(\d+)"""
                    ]
                },
                "letter_extracter_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": false,
                    "patterns": [
                        """([A-Z])+-\d+"""
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "number_extracter_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "number_extracter_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "letter_extracter_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "letter_extracter_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "model": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                    "number": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "number_extracter_analyzer"
                    },
                    "letters": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "letter_extracter_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample documents
PUT /numbers_in_pattern/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"model":"AR-123"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"model":"AR-1234"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"model":"AR-12345"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"model":"AR-123456"}

Search query with letters and number, search analyzer
GET /numbers_in_pattern/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "model.number": {
                "query": "AR-1234",
                "analyzer": "number_extracter_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "numbers_in_pattern",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 1.513566,
                "_source" : {
                    "model" : "AR-1234"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Another search query with only number
GET /numbers_in_pattern/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "model.number": "1234"
        }
    }
}

Response is the same
